# Getting 'ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel.' on training a model

Tags: tensorflow2.0, preprocessor, transformer-model, tf.data.dataset

I'm using Tensorflow 2 and LaBSE pre-trained model on tf-hub (not much familiar with both). (https://tfhub.dev/google/LaBSE/2). I am trying to train a multi class classifier with a custom text data set. I am also following this example on BERT classifier(https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert), to get the idea of how the model is built. This is to check only I can train and run the model. I am using data set objects for my input texts obtained from csv data which looks like this,

```
"Sentence","label"
"sentence sample1", 0
"sentence sample2", 3
```

and I split them into X, y sets as usual. However,
I get the above error when trying to train the model. Below is my code,

```
def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
  encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
  encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='LaBSE_encoder')
  outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooled_output']
  activation= tf.keras.activations.softmax#None
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=activation, name='classifier')(net)
  return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)

loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
metrics = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
epochs = 5
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( # convert to dataset objects
    np.array(X_train),np.array(y_train,dtype='int32')
  
))

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    np.array(X_test),np.array(y_test,dtype='int32')
    
))
```

These dataset objects' specs are, <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.int32)>

```
classifier_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                         loss=loss,
                         metrics=metrics)

his = classifier_model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset,
                               epochs=epochs, batch_size=8) #ignore that I'm using test dataset for validation dataset
```

The last step gives the error;

```
Epoch 1/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None,) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='text'), name='text', description="created by layer 'text'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape ().
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None,) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='text'), name='text', description="created by layer 'text'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape ().
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-3523a14b56f1> in <module>()
      1 history = classifier_model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset,
----> 2                                epochs=epochs, batch_size=8)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py:237 call  *
        result = smart_cond.smart_cond(training,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py:670 _call_attribute  **
        return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:889 __call__
        result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:924 _call
        results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:3022 __call__
        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:3444 _maybe_define_function
        graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:3289 _create_graph_function
        capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:999 func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:672 wrapped_fn
        out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/function_deserialization.py:291 restored_function_body
        "\n\n".join(signature_descriptions)))

    ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
        * True
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
        * True
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (3 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
        * False
        * None
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

I think this is an issue with the dataset object's specs provided to the input but, do not understand how to fix it or the exact reason. I do not get even though my dataset object has types of "tf.string" why it is incompatible with the input expected. I looked up in existing answers and since I'm not much familiar with TF, I want to know what is the reason and how could I fix this issue.